# VS Code debug can't resolve classes from import statements while it works fine using command line

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I'm working on some simple Data structures using Java and I'm using Princeton's library to implement the data structures but VS Code can't pick the files used under the import statements while it works fine if I compile and run the programs from the terminal.

Here's my Java code with comments depicting the situation:

```
//these imports work fine
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

//this is available in my local directory
    //VS code is unable to resolve these imports, however it works fine while using integrated terminal
    import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.Bag;
    import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdIn;
    import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdOut;


public class Stats {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // read in numbers
        Bag<Double> numbers = new Bag<Double>();

        int i = 0;
        while (i < args.length) {
            numbers.add(Double.parseDouble(args[i]));
            i++;
        }
        int n = numbers.size();

        // compute sample mean
        double sum = 0.0;
        for (double x : numbers)
            sum += x;
        double mean = sum / n;

        // compute sample standard deviation
        sum = 0.0;
        for (double x : numbers) {
            sum += (x - mean) * (x - mean);
        }
        double stddev = Math.sqrt(sum / (n - 1));

        StdOut.printf("Mean:    %.2f\n", mean);
        StdOut.printf("Std dev: %.2f\n", stddev);
    }
}
```

Here's what I receive in VS Code build errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    StdOut cannot be resolved
    StdOut cannot be resolved
```

can someone please help me with this? I'm using Java Extension Pack from Microsoft

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any IDE that is supposed to compile or run Java code needs to have the required classes available. In other words:

1. learn what **[class path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)** means in Java.
2. setup your IDE to know about all the 3rd party libraries/classes you intend to use, see the corresponding [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/java) for example.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I tried adding my path to both the Path and ClassPath environment variable under System Variables but unfortunately that didn't work. 

here's what `echo %CLASSPATH%` returns in cmd: `C:\Users\zeeAB\Desktop\Algorithms - Princeton\0 Programming in Java\algs4\algs4.jar;`

Comment: Dont put such information into comments. And what I tried to say in my answer: this can be quite a bit of work. You have to make sure that your class path setup is correct, and then you have to derive a meaningful project definition in your IDE. That is an essential part of you *learning* what you are doing.

Comment: I tried setting up the classpath, and path environment variable as well but no luck with anything since yesterday, everything works fine if I try to build my code using the terminal it's just VS code can't detect the external Java Classes, maybe I need to switch IDE.

Comment: What makes you think that VS code looks into these ENV vars? I think you are not getting the **key** element here: different IDEs have different ways to define and setup *projects*. It doesn't help to switch IDEs when you don't understand how to configure it properly. I can only repeat: read the documentation and learn how to correctly define a Java project with your IDE.

Comment: I believe you are right, I will spend some time into reading documentation and I hope to make it work, Thanks for the help  :)

Comment: I'm currently looking into this and if this answer leads me to solve this, I will accept it for sure so more people may get help. :)

Answer (score 0):

To add to GhostCat's answer (I am doing the same Coursera class from Princeton), this piece of information is helpful:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project

Tl;dr: I had to  add this to my `.classpath` file in the vscode project directory:

`<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/path_to_stdlib.jar" />`

Answer (score 0):

You can use maven to track all the dependence and then use the Maven for Java Extension which keep the track of pom.xml file changes and import the library in the project.

ref:https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-build